# How to let users know grid rows can be double clicked to show more detail?

Tags: grid, hints

I was using a web app and I double clicked on a row in a grid for kicks and it opened a section under the grid with extra information about the row's data. That wasn't obvious and discoverable.

What UI elements or indicators can be used to hint to the user that there's a double click option for each row. I know showing a tooltip when hovering over the grid is an option. I prefer more subtle hints.

Comment: I've seen apps and websites with "Did you know...?" boxes that pop up when you open the each time. The boxes show tips & tricks.  You could describe that feature there. However, many users won't read the "Did you know...?" tips, and many users will just disable that if given the chance.

Answer (score 1):

Educate your users. Use [onboarding](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/mobile-onboarding-beginners-guide/).

For example, when the customer opens a screen with a list for the first time, show him overlay with a tip:
[image]